# Recall same UI View controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have UI View controller and I want at some point to let it recall it self again so it will re init from the beginning.

How I can do it?

In Android I can do this even if I am already in MyActivity :

```
StartActivity(typeof(MyActivity));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this is either to re-initiate all the variables you need to a default value, or to put the view controller inside a container and recreate it every time you want to reset it.

Answer (score 2):

Create an "initialize" function:

```
func myInit() {
    // do my setup
    // set variables to defaults
    // set positions to defaults
    // etc
}
```

Then, where you currently do all that (often in viewDidLoad):

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.myInit()
}
```

Then, anytime you want to "re-init", just call `myInit()` again.